# Configure Azure file share backup with ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-arm-template, azure-backup

I was trying to configure Azure file share backup using ARM template deployment. 
Below is the template I'm trying to deploy. First I create a backup policy then trying to configure backup for the file share.

The question is, to the template I have to pass protected items in below format. (azurefileshare;someUniqueID) (I have to pass the unique protected item ID instead of file share name). But this ID can only be retrieved after configuring the backup.

Let me know if anyone here have any idea about this.

```
> "protectedItems": {
>             "value": [
>                 "azurefileshare;xxxx1f5e4535076cxxxxxxxxxxxb9ff558024ff8xxxxxxcefce6"
>             ]
>
```

Tempate.json

```
 >  {
    > "$schema":"http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    > "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",  
    >   "parameters": {
    >     "vaultName": {
    >       "type": "String"
    >     },
    >     "vaultRG": {
    >       "type": "String"
    >     },
    >     "vaultSubID": {
    >       "type": "String"
    >     },
    >     "policyName": {
    >       "type": "String"
    >     },
    >     "schedule": {
    >       "type": "Object"
    >     },
    >     "retention": {
    >       "type": "Object"
    >     },
    >     "timeZone": {
    >       "type": "String"
    >     },
    >     "fabricName": {
    >       "type": "String"
    >     },
    >     "protectionContainers": {
    >       "type": "Array"
    >     },
    >     "protectedItems": {
    >       "type": "Array"
    >     },
    >     "sourceResourceIds": {
    >       "type": "Array"
    >     }   },   "resources": [
    >     {
    >       "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies",
    >       "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
    >       "name": "[concat(parameters('vaultName'), '/', parameters('policyName'))]",
    >       "properties": {
    >         "backupManagementType": "AzureStorage",
    >         "WorkloadType": "AzureFileShare",
    >         "schedulePolicy": "[parameters('schedule')]",
    >         "retentionPolicy": "[parameters('retention')]",
    >         "TimeZone": "[parameters('timeZone')]"
    >       }
    >     },
    >     {
    >       "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/protectionContainers/protectedItems",
    >       "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
    >       "name": "[concat(parameters('vaultName'), '/', parameters('fabricName'),
    > '/',parameters('protectionContainers')[copyIndex()], '/',
    > parameters('protectedItems')[copyIndex()])]",
    >       "dependsOn": [
    >         "[concat('Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults', '/', parameters('vaultName'), '/backupPolicies/',
    > parameters('policyName'))]"
    >       ],
    >       "properties": {
    >         "backupManagementType": "AzureStorage",
    >         "workloadType": "AzureFileShare",
    >         "friendlyName": "afs",
    >         "protectedItemType": "AzureFileShareProtectedItem",
    >         "policyId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies',
    > parameters('vaultName'), parameters('policyName'))]",
    >         "sourceResourceId": "[parameters('sourceResourceIds')[copyIndex()]]"
    >       },
    >       "copy": {
    >         "name": "protectedItemsCopy",
    >         "count": "[length(parameters('protectedItems'))]"
    >       }
    >     }   ] }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here the same behavior.
It seems  the property format of **name** in this case is mandatory and not documented.

I have got success hardcoding  the long string  "661bd40fac4e36949e3e814039158f0b6c27ee8a497452559176d00f0cf257cb6"

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "vaultName": { "value": "blablabla" },
        "vaultRG": { "value": "rg-blablabla" },
        "policyName": { "value": "DailyPolicy" },
        "fabricName": { "value": "Azure" },
        "protectionContainers": {
          "value": [
            "storagecontainer;storage;rg-blablabla;storage002"
          ]
        },
        "protectedItems": {
          "value": [
           "azurefileshare;661bd40fac4e36949e3e814039158f0b6c27ee8a497452559176d00f0cf257cb6"
          ]
        },
        "sourceResourceIds": {
          "value": [
            "/subscriptions/ blabla bla /resourceGroups/rg-blablabla/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storage002"
          ]
        }
    }
}
```

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "parameters": {
              "vaultName": { "type": "string" },
              "vaultRG": { "type": "string" },
              "vaultSubID": { "type": "string" },
              "policyName": { "type": "string" },
              "fabricName": { "type": "string" },
              "protectionContainers": { "type": "array" },
              "protectedItems": { "type": "array" },
              "sourceResourceIds": { "type": "array" }
            },
    "resources": [
              {
                "name": "[concat(parameters('vaultName'), '/', parameters('fabricName'), '/',parameters('protectionContainers')[copyIndex()], '/', parameters('protectedItems')[copyIndex()])]",
                "apiVersion": "2020-02-02",
                "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/protectionContainers/protectedItems",
                "properties": {
                  "backupManagementType": "AzureStorage",
                  "workloadType": "AzureFileShare",
                  "friendlyName": "afs",
                  "protectedItemType": "AzureFileShareProtectedItem",
                  "policyId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies', parameters('vaultName'), parameters('policyName'))]",
                  "sourceResourceId": "[parameters('sourceResourceIds')[copyIndex()]]"
                },
                "copy": {
                  "name": "protectedItemsCopy",
                  "count": "[length(parameters('protectedItems'))]"
                }
              }
    ]
}
```

It is not complete functional, but it works

Comment: 0

@MiGel0 Hope you are are doing good. I have tried various time with the same arm template to backup azure file share of azure storage, though struggling with same error as mentioned below:

The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed' Microsoft Azure Backup encountered an internal error.

Kindly advise how to overcome on this.

Comment: Kindly also share me how can i get this unique value 661bd40fac4e36949e3e814039158f0b6c27ee8a497452559176d00f0cf257cb6" or can i put any random value ?

Comment: IT's my fault. The long string its and example,  as far as understand  you have to extract this string  using the API. Maybe this is th reason of the error.

Comment: Could you advise me how to extract that string using API or any other way.Also How will we manage if we have various fileshare in a storage to take backup

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this article answers your question; https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-file-share-rest-api

In the article they describe that you can use the `name` property from the [GET backupprotectableItems](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/backup/backupprotectableitems/list) API. In their example they show the name as `azurefiles;<name of your fileshare>`, but this is actually `azurefiles;<some random ID>`. As they themself say;

> Always take the name attribute of the response and fill it in this request. Don't hard-code or create the container-name format or protected item name format. If you create or hard-code it, the API call will fail if the container-name format or protected item name format changes in the future.